# payfort "response_message":"Invalid command with TOKENIZATION

Tags: php, asp.net, amazon-web-services, payfort

i am using payfort for payment process

when send request to payfort api to give me a token_name the response from request make return payfort  `"response_message":"Invalid command` with `TOKENIZATION`

i active Merchant page channel in payfort profile and set all information inside it like redirection link and url and soo on

and send all mandatory param with successful signature you can see request param in this following document

[payfort document](https://paymentservices-reference.payfort.com/docs/api/build/index.html#custom-merchant-page-integration-request)

i am using spring boot and try send request from postman and angular form to my api and then redirect to payfortAPI after handling signature

i am using test url enviroment to test transaction from payfort

and i  try send request from post man to  test url enviroment  from payfort without using spring boot but will return same response

and the following here my code

```
@Data
public class Payment extends Signature implements ISignature{


    private String expiry_date;
    private String card_number;
    private String card_security_code;
    private String paymentSignature;
    private String card_holder_name;

/*
    public Payment(){
        super();
    }*/

    public String getSignature(){
        return paymentSignature;
    }

    public void setSignature() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        paymentSignature=createSign();
    }

    @Override
    public String createSign() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        Map<String, Object> requestMap = new HashMap<>();
        requestMap.put("service_command", this.getService_command());
        requestMap.put("access_code", this.getAccess_code());
        requestMap.put("merchant_identifier", this.getMerchant_identifier());
        requestMap.put("merchant_reference", this.getMerchant_reference());
        requestMap.put("language", this.getLanguage());
        requestMap.put("expiry_date", this.getExpiry_date());
        requestMap.put("card_number", this.getCard_number());
        requestMap.put("card_security_code", this.getCard_security_code());
        requestMap.put("card_holder_name",this.getCard_holder_name());

        //order by key
        requestMap = requestMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));

        String requestString = "saAbdalrhman0788&*";
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: requestMap.entrySet())
            requestString += entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue();
        requestString+= "Abdalrhman0788&*";

        System.out.println("requestString = " + requestString);

        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hashed = digest.digest(requestString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String signature = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hashed);
        System.out.println("signature = " + signature);

        return signature;
    }
```

and here my service to call payfort api

```
 public String CreateTokenization(Payment payment) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, URISyntaxException {
    fillTokenization(payment);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-type", "application/json" );


    Map<String,Object>  body=new HashMap<>();
    body.put("service_command",payment.getService_command());
    body.put("access_code",payment.getAccess_code());
    body.put("merchant_identifier", payment.getMerchant_identifier());
    body.put("merchant_reference", payment.getMerchant_reference());
    body.put("expiry_date",payment.getExpiry_date());
    body.put("card_number",payment.getCard_number());
    body.put("card_security_code",payment.getCard_security_code());
    body.put("signature",payment.getSignature());

    // add request param before send the request to amazon payment api
    URI uri = new URI(testEnvironment);

    HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> res= restTemplate.postForEntity(uri,request,String.class);
    System.out.println("res = " + res.toString());
    return res.toString();

}
```

and i will send this data to payment

```
{
"service_command":"TOKENIZATION",
"access_code":"LVQEEDAfI1qbZW0wXbsb",
"merchant_identifier":"5f803bfd",
"merchant_reference":"00658azx1",
"language":"en",
"expiry_date":"1125",
"card_number":"4005550000000001",
"card_security_code":"123",
```

"signature":"35D8D45435741D40619E947B0A8A7C8675BBD42FCB0C2BFC12C519CEE48F3B3F"}

and this is my full response from payfort

```
<200,{"response_code":"00004","service_command":"TOKENIZATION","card_number":"400555******0001","response_message":"Invalid command","signature":"da3f35fe27802719db31e500674025fa14d255c74a66c7005d2a720bb437e0ed","merchant_identifier":"5f803bfd","merchant_reference":"00658azx1","access_code":"BhSPWubm9lsp577tsv7J","expiry_date":"1125","status":"00"},[Date:"Thu, 28 Oct 2021 21:11:17 GMT", Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"345", Connection:"keep-alive", Accept-Charset:"big5, big5-hkscs, cesu-8, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, ibm285, ibm290, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500, ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862, ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871, ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8, iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis, tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be, utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-hkscs-2001, x-big5-solaris, x-compound_text, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006, x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122, x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm1166, x-ibm1364, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383, x-ibm300, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856, x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935, x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c, x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970, x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11, x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope, x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew, x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai, x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs, x-ms950-hkscs-xp, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom, x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp", X-Amzn-Trace-Id:"Root=1-617b11f5-fcab24484764e302621fd107;", X-Powered-By:"Undertow/1", CF-Cache-Status:"DYNAMIC", Expect-CT:"max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"", Server:"cloudflare", CF-RAY:"6a5727dccd6e5caa-FRA"]>
```

> if send invalid sign will return the same response

Comment: Can you please share an example of your request, and the full output of the response.

Comment: i updated with ```createSign()``` , request method ```CreateTokenization```  then you can see body of request and finally you can see response from ```payfort``` @JacobMulquin

Answer (score 1):

i found the error in signature just remove following line

```
    requestMap.put("expiry_date", this.getExpiry_date());
    requestMap.put("card_number", this.getCard_number());
    requestMap.put("card_security_code", this.getCard_security_code());
    requestMap.put("card_holder_name",this.getCard_holder_name());
```

because i found this note in payfort document

> Remember - Please don’t include the following parameters in
> calculating the signature if you are using the custom merchant page
> integration tokenization request: card_security_code, card number,
> expiry_date, card_holder_name, remember_me.

Answer (score 0):

The only **required** parameter you must pass for TOKENIZATION will be.

```
'service_command'     => 'TOKENIZATION',
            'merchant_reference'  => your merchant Reference,
            'access_code'         => your access code,
            'merchant_identifier' => your merchant id,
            'language'            => your preferred language in payment,
             'return_url'          => your return url where you will get  response of payfort,
```

For further you have to use **PURCHASE** command if the previous response code will be  18000.

Comment: This is quite right. I vouch for this.